# Selfroles but with Buttons instead of Reactions

Tags: discord, discord.py

me and some friends run a Gaming Server and for that we've created a discord.
On this Game we have subscriptions for some benefits in the Game and we want to include them to the Discord.

We want to have a Channel where they're listed three Tiers of Subscriptions T1 - T3.
As soon as a Player gets a Subscripton, they get the role manually from us after cheking the Payment (Role: Donator T1)
Now we would want them to have as soon as they have this role to be able to see this channel (we did this with normal Roles in discord to be visable).
Now they're should be 3 Messages where they can see T1 - T3 Subscriptions with Buttons to press on for ex. to get the Color they want.

Now if they dont have the T2 Subscription (Role Donator T2 or T3) the Buttons for T2 and T3 should be Grey and they should get a warning message.
If they have the T2 they should only be able to click the buttons for T1 and T2 - T3 should be grey and disabled.

If made a visualization of this for better understanding:
[image]

I've seen in the Documentation that you can do buttons relativly easy but is it possible to disable them on behalf of a missing role?
Would be awesome if someone could help me.

Thanks in advance.

tried looking up stuff on youtube and the python discord but couldnt find anything specific for this

Comment: You can't outrightly disable a button because disabling a button is globalised, meaning if you disable the button, it is disabled for everyone. You can add a check in the button callback to check for the required role (and maybe send an error message). However, we won't code it for you. If you would like help, provide us with what you've tried, the error you got, and read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more

Comment: @raymus i can see what you mean by the question ... i get that i didnt type it that well - this is cause im not native and tried it on the fly. What i meant was like a general Question if its even possible. Guess i wrote it wrong, anyways ty for the answer that helped alot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if you can modify buttons on-the-fly for different users. If I'm not wrong, buttons that are added to messages are the same for everyone. A way you can make something custom though is by building the function that comes with the button.

After having created a view using `view = discord.ui.View()`

```py
mybutton = discord.ui.Button(label="My Button", style=discord.ButtonStyle.blue)
```

For every button can then be "attached" a function, a callback, like

```py
mybutton.callback = mycallback
```

You can then check everything you need inside that callback function. If you have a list of users `authorised_users` that have the authorisation to click the button, you could simply ignore the other clicks by setting for example

```py
async def mycallback(interaction: discord.Interaction):
    if interaction.user not in authorised_users:
        return
    # some function for the authorised users.
```

Hope this helps !

Comment: thanks - this helped alot .. i wasnt sure if its possible or not and you gave me even more with it. have a good day